# onClick event isn't firing on React Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a component stub where I have a grid of tiles, each that require a click handler, and also a specific "new" tile that has a different click handler. I'm trying to get the click handlers working correctly, but the event never seems to fire.

Any ideas?

```
var grid = React.createClass({
    onCreateNew: function () {
        console.log("onCreateNew");
    },
    render: function () {
        var tiles = [];
        if (this.props.items) {
            tiles = this.props.items.map(function (item, index) {
                //create a tile for each item
            });
        }
        //always append "new" tile for the last one
        tiles.push(React.DOM.div({
            onClick: this.onCreateNew, className: "tile new_tile"
        },
            React.DOM.div({ className: "plus", onClick: this.onCreateNew }, "+")
        ));            
        return React.DOM.div({ id: "flowsheetPane" }, tiles);
    }
});
```

Comment: I pasted your code into the [base React JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjeux/kb3gN/) and it seems to work fine ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/3137/)).

Comment: You're right. That's very odd. Now I have to figure out why it's not working in my environment.

Comment: Does it matter that this component is nested a few children deep?

Comment: Are you binding the other onClick inside the `map` call? Be sure to pass `this` as the context if you plan to reference the component otherwise `this` will equal `window`: `this.props.items.map(function() ..., this);`

Comment: Do you get any console error?

Comment: Did you solve the thing? I am getting the same problem with no console error!!

Comment: Could stopPropagation or another eventListener be being added by another JS script that you have on the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commenters have mentioned, your code appears to work as expected in isolation.

React delegates to event handlers with a single event listener at the root of the DOM, so events need to propagate all the way to the top in order for React to call your function.

Could you have added some event listeners somewhere in the component hierarchy that are calling `event.stopPropagation()`?  If you did this outside of React (e.g. natively or with jquery), it would cause the events to never reach the top of the DOM, and React would never have a chance to delegate out to your methods.