# export javascript function using React

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I am trying to do the facebook login for a website. What I post is a segment of a js file with a render function that returns this html code:

```
var hellojs = require('./hello.js');

// See what hello.js does: http://adodson.com/hello.js/demos/profile.html#helloapi-me-
//It basically prompts the facebook window to sign up. 
var React = require('react');

var provide rs = {
facebook : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
twitter  : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',//I have registered my app, XX.. is just for privacy. 
google   : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
};
//LISTENER FOR LOGIN

hellojs.hello.on('auth.login',function(auth){
    hellojs.hello(auth.network).api('/me').then(function(response){
    var object = {};
    debugger;
    if (auth.network === 'twitter' || auth.network === 'facebook'){
        object.username = response.name;
        object.providerId = response.id.toString();
        object.thumbnail = response.thumbnail;
    }
    object.providerType = auth.network;
    sessionActions.authenticated(object);
   });
});
/*Sign Up component*/
login: function(event){
    var object = {};
    var provider = event.currentTarget.name;
    object[provider] = providers[provider];

    hellojs.hello.init(object,{
        'redirect_uri' : 'localhost',
        'oauth_proxy'  : 'https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/proxy',
        scope: 'publish_actions'
    });
    hellojs.hello.login(provider);
},
render: function() {
    .....
    return (
        <div className="signup col-sm-4">
            <form className="form-horizontal" role="form" id="login-form">
                .....
                <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-sm-offset-2">
                        <button onClick={this.login} 
                        class='zocial facebook'>Sign in with Facebook</button> 
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
```

When I compile, and click on the 'Sign in with Facebook' button, nothing happens. I am little bit confused, because I tried it with the following simple html file, and it worked perfectly:

```
<script> src='hello.js'></script>
<button onClick="{this.login}">Sign in with Facebook</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a casing issue.  Change `onclick` to `onClick`.  JSX turns into javascript, so casing does matter.

That still may not work though, since `hello` is not in the global scope, and it may need to be in order to be executed from within HTML elements.  Instead, add a method to your component that calls to `hello.hello()`.

```
doLogin: function() {
    hello.hello('facebook').login()
},
render: function() {
    .....
    return (
        <div className="signup col-sm-4">
            <form className="form-horizontal" role="form" id="login-form">
                .....
                <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-sm-offset-2">
                        <button onClick={this.doLogin} 
                        class='zocial facebook'>Sign in with Facebook</button> 
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Hi Sean, I implemented your suggestion, but it still does not work. Actually, it won't even charge if I don't delete the LOGIN LISTENER. I would really appreciate if you could take a look at it sometime. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your updated question, it looks like you have `{this.login}` wrapped in quotes, which is wrong.  Putting quotes around it will interpret it as a string, when you actually want it to be a reference to the javascript function.  Change `onClick="{this.login}"` to `onClick={this.login}`, and it should call the function on click.

Comment: I had done a mistake with the copy-paste. The original code was not wrapped in quotes, but it still does nothing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are saying if you put a breakpoint right inside your `login` function, it never get's hit when clicking the button?  We'll need to see more code in order to help then, since there is no reason that wouldn't work, unless you had other things going on.  You might try checking out my answer on this other question for a possibility of what could be wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335218/onclick-event-isnt-firing-on-react-component/26393499#26393499